# Problem using Maximum Modulus principle

Tags: complex-analysis

I am solving a problem as follows:
Suppose $f$ is analytic on the disc $|z|<1$ and satisfies $|f(z)|<M$ if $|z|<$1.

Suppose that $f(a) = 0$ for some $a, |a|<1$. Then, show that

$$ 
|f(z)| \le M \cdot \left| \frac{z-a}{1-a'z} \right|
$$

where $a'$ is the complex conjugate of $a$.

I know that the fraction has a modulus of at most $1$, using the same argument found here
[Maximum modulus principle exercise.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384745/maximum-modulus-principle-exercise)

I am not sure how to show the inequality above.

Thank you

Comment: What is the definition of $M$?

Comment: Sorry, I made an error. It should be clear what M is now.

Answer (score 3):

Define, $g(z)=\frac{f}{M}\circ\varphi_{-a}(z)$, where $\varphi_\alpha(z)=\frac{z-\alpha}{1-\bar\alpha z}$.

So, $g:U \to U$ a holomorphic function, where $U$ is the unit disc, and $g(0)=0$.

Now apply [*Schwarz Lemma*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma#Statement), to conclude that $|g(z)| \leq |z|$ for all $z\in U$. Now notice that $\varphi_a\circ \varphi_{-a}=Id$.

Hence, replace $z$ with $\varphi_a(z)$ and get $|f(z)| \leq M \cdot \left| \frac{z-a}{1-a'z} \right|$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: let $g(z) = \dfrac{z-a}{1-z\bar a}$ and consider the function $h(z) = f(z)/g(z)$.

Comment: Sorry but I am not sure what introducing the function h(z) is supposed to achieve.

Comment: @user64742 Note that $h$ is holomorphic on the unit disc. What can you say about $|h|$ near $|z|=1$? Now use the maximum modulus principle (on a slightly smaller disc if you want to be pedantic).

Comment: Near |z|=1, |h| = |f|. On the interior of the unit disc, |h| > |f|. I am trying to solve this problem mostly computationally (using inequalities rather than the max modulus principle), mostly because I don't really understand the maximum modulus principle well enough

Comment: What I'm tying to say is that I need to prove that $|f| \le M \cdot |g|$ and it doesn't really help my cause that $|g| < 1$.